# GUI is non responsive while updating grid having 80 columns during heavy update

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

I am having an application which is for securities trading in stock exchange. It has real time market feed from one of the vendors. We are processing market data on worker thread(s) and while updating main GUI we are marshaling this data to GUI thread.

Let me make this more clear, there is an ultragrid (third party gridview) having 80 columns, we have around 40 rows with same security that must be updated as and when there is fluctuation in market data. We are able to handle market frequency of 10 messages/sec/security. But beyond that we are unable to handle. GUI becomes non-responsive when frequency increases to 25-30 msgs/sec/security. We have followed best practices while designing and implementation but still we can not handle high freq. We are performing all non-GUI specific work on worker/back-ground threads, but still facing GUI hang. Please help in suggesting me any out of the box solution to tackle this problem. Here I can not put code snippet due to security reasons.

Comment: This is obviously caused by the brokers, they are not reading the messages fast enough.  You'll need to tell them they need to do a better job of keeping up.

Comment: Soo... that's 80 columns, 40 rows and 25-30 updates *per row* each second?  Is that right?  If so, as Hans implies, most of your updates are redundant unless you have some sort of super-broker who can take this in and act on it!  Restrict updates for each row to a rate that is more human-readable, dumping all others.

Answer (score 0):

Switch your grid component to something that can double buffer and multithread (I expect most data will remain static around updates), or roll your own. Rolling your own sounds unavoidable: this kind of heavy update activity isn't the most common use case for grid controls. I'd start looking for grid controls with open source code you can modify, at e.g. http://www.codeproject.com or http://www.codeplex.com. What to pick depends on your other requirements, alas.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing here is to virtualise everything - the only interaction between your data model and the grid should be when the relevant cells need to be painted.  In order to do this you will need to use a grid that supports this kind of virtualisation (I've used a Syncfusion grid to do this before, see example [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/SyncFusionVirtualGrid11302005020013AM/SyncFusionVirtualGrid.aspx)).

You will also want to batch the updates to your data model so that you don't block the GUI thread too frequently.  Have a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728021/wpf-real-time-multithreaded-stock-trading-application).